# The button disappear after clicked in toggle class in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have button (like heart) and I try to toggle between activae (red heard) and remove active class when I click in button it shows red but it dissapear after that

```
  <button id="post_like_button_acc" class="like_button" @click="addLike(comment.id, $el,index,)" ref="Post_LikeButtonAcc">
                       <div class='large-font text-center top-20'>
                          <ion-icon name="heart" class="like_comment" :class="{ active: activeItem  == comment.id  }">
                            <div class='red-bg' ></div> 
                          </ion-icon>
                        </div>
                    <p class="" style="red; margin-left: 10px; color: white" ></p>
                    </button>



   async addLike(id, el){
       this.activeItem = id;
    }
```

The css of heart icon

```
    ion-icon.active{
  animation:like 0.5s 1;
  fill:red;
  stroke:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using :hover and :active in the CSS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/CSS/:active
https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Answer (score 0):

The solution to get the div of the element in array by add `el` to the funtion
`addLike(id, el)` this you can get hte div after that use `let icon = el.querySelector('ion-icon');`

```
 async addLike(id, el){
    var button_clicked = $(el)
        this.activeItem = id;
            if(this.activeItem = id){
                     let icon = el.querySelector('ion-icon');
                    icon.classList.toggle('active');
            }
    }
```